# custom UserCreationForm in Forms.py won't import into Views.py

Tags: python-3.x, django-views, django-forms

I am new to Python and Django and I'm trying to create a basic user authentication system. I want to add an extra email field in the user registration. I don't understand why the UserCreationForm won't import into views.py. I also created a regular forms.Form for the user login in the same forms.py folder and it imports fine into views.py.

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class UserLoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField()
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
        username = self.cleaned_data.get('username')
        password = self.cleaned_data.get('password')

        if username and password:
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

            if not user:
                raise forms.ValidationError('This user does not exist')
            if not user.check_password(password):
                raise forms.ValidationError('Incorrect password')
            if not user.is_active:
                raise forms.ValidationError('This user is not active')
        return super(UserLoginForm, self).clean(*args, **kwargs)

    class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
        email = forms.EmailField(label='Email address')
        email2 = forms.EmailField(label='Confirm email')

        class Meta:
            model = User
            fields = [
                'username',
                'email',
                'email2',
                'password'
            ]

        def clean_email(self):
            email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
            email2 = self.cleaned_data.get('email2')
            if email != email2:
                raise forms.ValidationError("emails must match")
            email_qs = User.objects.filter(email=email)
            if email_qs.exists():
                raise forms.ValidationError(
                    "This email is already being used"
                )
            return email
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import (
    authenticate,
    login,
    logout
)

from .forms import UserLoginForm 

from .forms import UserRegisterForm


def login_view(request):
    next = request.GET.get('next')
    form = UserLoginForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
        password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        login(request, user)
        if next:
            return redirect(next)
        return redirect('/')

    context = {
        'form': form,
    }

    return render(request, 'login.html', context)


def register_view(request):
    next = request.GET.get('next')
    form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        user = form.save(commit=False)
        password = form.save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        new_user = authenticate(username=user.username, password=password)
        login(request, new_user)
        if next:
            return redirect(next)
        return redirect('/')

    context = {
        'form': form,
    }

    return render(request, 'signup.html', context)


def logout_view(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect('/')
```

Answer (score 0):

So basically your indentation was off in `forms.py`

Here is the fixed indentation code:

```py
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class UserLoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField()
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
        username = self.cleaned_data.get('username')
        password = self.cleaned_data.get('password')

        if username and password:
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

            if not user:
                raise forms.ValidationError('This user does not exist')
            if not user.check_password(password):
                raise forms.ValidationError('Incorrect password')
            if not user.is_active:
                raise forms.ValidationError('This user is not active')
        return super(UserLoginForm, self).clean(*args, **kwargs)

class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(label='Email address')
    email2 = forms.EmailField(label='Confirm email')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
            'username',
            'email',
            'email2',
            'password'
        ]

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        email2 = self.cleaned_data.get('email2')
        if email != email2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("emails must match")
        email_qs = User.objects.filter(email=email)
        if email_qs.exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                "This email is already being used"
            )
        return email
```

Comment: @Jie-LiangLin You might want to consider accepting the answer if it solved your issue to let anyone know the issue incase they stumble upon the same :)

Comment: Not able to accept answers yet..I guess I need 15 points..

Comment: @Jie-LiangLin Ah okay got it. My bad. Nevermind